# Complexity of exponential functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity

We are given $f(x) = x^{x^2}$ and $g(x) = 2^{2^x}$. The question is to determine whether $f = O(g)$, $\Omega(g)$, or $\Theta(g)$. Because $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ intersect at $x=2$ and $f(x)$ grows faster than $g(x)$ after this point, is it correct to say that $f(x) = \Omega(g)$ as:

$$|f(x)| \ge C \cdot |g(x)|, \forall x > k$$

for some constants $C$ and $k$ where $C = 1$ and $k = 1$.

Comment: "...and $f(x)$ grows faster than $g(x)$ after this point..." <--- this is what you have to prove.

Comment: @AntonioVargas How would you go about proving that?

Comment: Yes, that is the question you should be asking.

Comment: It might help to take a look at the log of both functions to compare them. If one log isn't enough, keep going.